# how to run two react project through nginx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, react-router

I am using the react for the frontend. I have a code which runs on port 3000.

Under that admin panel code is also there which I need to move to out of the project and run separately on different port let's say 3001.
So on nginx config file
I have created the location for both the project like this

```
Under server block
location /admin/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
            
        }

location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
```

By this way  when I open the localhost, my code is running properly.

Now if I type localhost/admin/ then it return 404.

For the nginx route confirmation, I have change the title of admin panel index.html so that it is clearly mentioned that whether my routes of nginx are working or not
So after this when I hit the admin url then through inspect element I saw that title are changed but due to routes issue of main server it return 404.

What it seems like it pick the both the route at same time. So after hit the admin url instant index.html page is load and then routes load from 3000 port project instead of 3001. On 3000 port project there is no such route like this hence it return 404.

Anyone have any idea how to tackle this type of Issues.

Both project are running fine if run individually through the port number like localhost:3000/ or localhost:3001/admin/

Any help or suggestion is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you have given 3001 port to /admin route. It will run on that port itself.

localhost by default listens to default port 80
localhost/admin will listen to 80 unless you specify.

You can make two server blocks and give different server names.

```
server {
    listen 3000;
}

server {
    listen 3001;
}
```

Comment: multi server blocks works when we have different domain. I want it on the same domain then different route like xyz.com connect to port 3000 and xyz.com/admin/ connect to port 3001.
I am on localhost for dvelopment phase and tried this approach but it not worked

Comment: Can you through some light clearly so that I will get some clue how to tackle this. Hope You well understand the query. And forgot to say thanks for the Help.